# About the partition of some reciprocals

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, harmonic-numbers

Does there exists a partition of the reciprocals $\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3},\cdots,\frac{1}{12}$, into two sets $A$ and $B$ such that $\displaystyle\sum_A\frac{1}{n} -\sum_B\frac{1}{n}=1$?

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you at least added them up to find what the sum over A and B need to be?

Comment: **Hint:** $7$ is a prime number and $\frac{1}{7}$ would be in exactly one of the sets.

Comment: This hint doesn't work for me. 2, 3, 5 and 11 are also primes in the list. How they contribute?

Comment: @matthew:  $11$ works the same way as $7$.  Think of putting the sum over a common denominator.

Comment: You don't want a partition of the reciprocals - you want a partition of the integers, since your sums are of the form $\sum_{n \in A} 1/n$.

Comment: As mentioned, $11$ will force the same conclusion as $7$, but $2,3,5$ will be more difficult to use to force a conclusion because there are multiple denominators which share prime factors with these.  Note for example $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{6}=1$ despite $3$ being prime.

Comment: @marty cohen: Partition of a set of reciprocals.

Comment: $\nu_2(H_{12})=-3$ hence such partition does not exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $k=\frac{12!}{7}=1\cdot2\cdot3\cdots6\cdot8\cdots12=68428800$.  Notice that $k$ is an integer and $\gcd(k,7)=1$

> We could have chosen a smaller $k$, for example $\text{lcm}(1,2,3,\dots,6,8,\dots,12)=3960$, but it really doesn't change anything in the proof and it makes it clearer hopefully what is going on.

Then $k\left(\sum\limits_{A}\frac{1}{n}-\sum\limits_{B}\frac{1}{n}\right)=k$

Moving the term $\frac{k}{7}$ to one side and all other terms to the other side, we have:

$\frac{k}{7}=\pm k\pm\frac{k}{2}\pm\frac{k}{3}\pm\dots\pm\frac{k}{6}\pm\frac{k}{8}\pm\dots\pm\frac{k}{12}$

> Each of the numbers on the right an integer so it follows that their sum and difference are as well.  (*Why?*)  What about the left side?  What does this imply?

Comment: This simply means that such a partition does not exists!